# How implement multiple editable column with yii-booster?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Am working on a Yii staff-hours scheduling project, stuck on editable-curd-staffhours-module. I want to store staff scheduling hours in `StaffHours`table using Editable [Yii Booster Extension](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/index.html).

My `staffhours` table DB stucture as:

`id(pk) user_id(fk) staff_id(int) monday(text) tuesday(text) wednesday(text)    thursday(text)  friday(text) saturday(text) sunday(text)`

All day-text fields used to store serialize time as in associative-array format:

```
array(
 '12:00 AM' => 'open',
 '12:30 AM' => 'close',
 '01:00 AM' => 'close',
 '01:30 AM' => 'open',
 '02:00 AM' => 'open',
 .
 .
 .
 '11:00 PM' => 'close'
 '11:30 PM' => 'close'
);
```

I have implemented Editable UI using [Yii Booster Extension](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/index.html), watch snap below:

**Problem** is that am unable to recognize how to store/update staff-hours data in DB.

[image]

**Some Of Code** i have done

**---- In View ----**

```
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Settings'=>array('settings/settings'),
    'Staff Hours',
);  
        $user_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
        $condition = "user_id = '$user_id'";
        $data = StaffHours::model()->findAll();
        $Monday = unserialize($data[0]['monday']);
        $Tuesday = unserialize($data[0]['tuesday']);
        $Wednesday = unserialize($data[0]['wednesday']);
        $Thursday = unserialize($data[0]['thursday']);
        $Friday = unserialize($data[0]['friday']);
        $Saturday = unserialize($data[0]['saturday']);
        $Sunday = unserialize($data[0]['sunday']);
        foreach($data as $data)
        {
?>

    <div id="settinghead">StaffS Hours </div>
        <div id="leftmenu"> <?php $this->widget('application.components.widgets.SettingsMenu.settingsmenuWidget'); ?></div>
        <div id="rightcontent">
            <div id="pageheding">Staff Hours Detail </div>
                <table class="items table table-bordered">
                <thead> 
                <tr><th scope="col">Time</th>   <th scope="col">Monday</th> <th scope="col">Tuesday</th><th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
                <th scope="col">Thursday</th><th scope="col">Friday</th><th scope="col">Saturday</th><th scope="col">Sunday</th> </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <?php 
                $start = strtotime('12:00am');
                $end = strtotime('11:59pm');
                for( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900) 
                {   
                    $time = date('h:i A', $i);
                ?>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $time; ?></th>
                    <td id="mon<?php echo $time; ?>">
                    <?php  
                    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableField', array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'model' => $data,
                        'emptytext' => $Monday[$time],
                        'attribute' => 'monday',
                        'url' => $this->createUrl('staffhours/updatetime&time='.$time), //url for submit data
                        'source' => array('Open', 'Close', 'Away'),
                        'value' => $time,
                        'enabled' => true
                    )); 
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td id="tue<?php echo date('g:i A', $i); ?>"><?php echo $Tuesday[$time]; ?></td>
                    <td id="wed<?php echo date('g:i A', $i); ?>"><?php echo $Wednesday[$time]; ?></td>
                    <td id="thu<?php echo date('g:i A', $i); ?>"><?php echo $Thursday[$time]; ?></td>
                    <td id="fri<?php echo date('g:i A', $i); ?>"><?php echo $Friday[$time]; ?></td>
                    <td id="sat<?php echo date('g:i A', $i); ?>"><?php echo $Saturday[$time]; ?></td>
                    <td id="sun<?php echo date('g:i A', $i); ?>"><?php echo $Sunday[$time]; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php
                }
            }
                ?>
                </table>
        </div>
```

**---- In StaffHoursController Controller ----**

```
/**
 * Update time.
 */
public function actionUpdatetime($time)
{
    $user_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $pk = $_POST['pk'];
    $day = $_POST['name'];
    $status = $_POST['value'];
    $GetData = StaffHours::model()->findByPk($pk);
    $DayTimes = unserialize($GetData->monday);
    if(array_key_exists($time, $DayTimes))
    {
        unset($DayTimes[$time]);
        //merge new value
        $DayTimes[$time] = $status;
        array_push($DayTimes, $DayTimes[$time]);
        $attributes = array($day => serialize($DayTimes));
        $condition = "id = '$pk' AND user_id = '$user_id'";
        StaffHours::model()->updateByPk($pk, $attributes, $condition);
    }
}
```

If am going wrong or another easy way available to staff hours using Editable-UI.

Then please suggest a better way to store Staff-Hours using Editable-UI.

Answer (score 2):

I believe storing array data into MySql text column is very impractical, since you will loose performance, ability to implement proper searching technique and etc. A better database design can be:
Each staff has many hours, and each hour can be assigned to many staff, a simple MANY_MANY relationship.
The advantage is that you can search for any date, any hour, any staff with a very easy,simple, singe query, or ActiveRecord:[image]

Comment: I made it, by Ajax. I used to serialize all time of particular day and store in db.
Thanks for your thoughts